# Potential solution for a NLP clustering problem

Tags: nlp, clustering, data-analysis

Trying to approach this clustering-based problem

Let's imagine I have a dataset containing millions of observations in a tabular data set, containing categorical, time-based, numerical, and text columns. (text column is basically a manual description uploaded by the user, detailing the complaint). Historically these complaints are raised by automatic systems or people. Many a time multiple systems or people raised the same issue, resulting in multiple individual complaints. Complaints that map to the same issue should most of the time should look similar in terms of features, according to my observation. My task is to cluster them in a way so that I can identify which complaints belong to the same problem. Historically I have data that tells me which complaints were duplicates.

Now my initial approach was to do some hierarchal clustering but got stuck on some issues-

How to accommodate text-based columns in clustering algorithms?
Given I have label data, is there is way to leverage this to develop a better clustering algorithm?
Any links or papers would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Note - CLusters are not few. for example in 24 hr period, there will be 100k complaints of which ~40k will be duplicates and 60k will be unique.

Comment: I am not sure that I would consider clustering the right way to go for this problem. If it were me, I would think about  a multi-stage process, true AI, not just one model. Use business logic combined with traditional NLP methods to assign similarity between the descriptions and then use all the other variables to create a filter, if the fields other than the time and the description would be the same, you could just say if these 7 fields are the same and similarty is greater than X% or you could use a topic model and say if these 7 fields are the same and topics are X% similar

Comment: What labels do you have ? How many unique labels ?

Comment: Use existing data to prepare supervised word embedding . There are lots of tutorials on how to prepare word embedding.  If your labels include problem type, then it  can be solved by a classification model such as navier bayes or SVM. Else if labels are unique / duplicate only, then word embedding will be unsupervised.